# Interface builder can't open xib file

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder, xib, xcode3

When I try to open the .xib file of my project, the Interface builder show me this error message:

> "Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "MainMenu.xib"."

Comment: Did you open .xib with Xcode?

Comment: Yes, like always did

Comment: Open with a text editor or hex editor and see what's strange about it.  (Compare to a known good file.)  Generally the type of a file is identified somehow in the first dozen or so bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem (after resolved git conflict) and I solved it by:

```
1. opening xib file in TextEdit 
2. duplicate file 
3. overwrite existing file
```

I hope so it help you to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just solve it. The problem was the major changes in the xml that the new version of xcode introduced in the document.